# My port is grayed out?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, uploading

Hello I have a question on why my port is grayed out when I go to upload?

I’ve watched so many YouTube videos on what’s the problem and have been trying to do everything but just nothing seems to work! Also, in device manager under ports (COM & LPT) the ports have an error sign over it. If someone can help me through this that would be fantastic!

The error when uploading:

problem uploading to board.
Sketch uses 2838 bites (8%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes . Global variables use 9bites (0%) Of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bites for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.avrdude: ser_open(): can’t open the voice “\.\COM”: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: In the device manager you can also open the details windows for that device (don't remember how it is called exactly in the context menu when you right click on the device. Please tells us what error message you can find there. Maybe you need to install the correct driver.

Comment: Error : Windows cannot determine the settings for this device. Consult the documentation that came with the device and use the resource tab to set the configuration.(code 34)

Comment: Be sure you have the appropriate driver loaded.

Comment: Genuine Arduino or CH340 based chinese clone?